# What is the correct way to set config options to a juju service unit with a file?

Tags: juju, charms

I need to set some secondary config options to a service charm deployed with juju. All of the options needed are preset to empty in the original config.yaml file. Now, some of those settings are changed in a separate config file named `extra-config.yaml`. How does one set these file config options to the service charm with the config-changed hook triggering? Also, can the extra-config.yaml be placed outside the charms directory structure?

This command works, but the config-changed hook is not triggered -->

`juju set --config precise/cool-charm/extra-config.yaml cool-charm`

Note: The docs provide a --file option which is not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is working as of now (6-21-12) with the current beta version of juju. One needs to issue a
`juju set charm-name --config /path/to/extra-config.yaml`
It is important to change the config file or add a revision field for the
*config-changed* hook to trigger. The hook will not trigger if the extra config file was previously set and is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a bug from what I can tell.  Just filed it as https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1015645